# how to compute value on columns with formula

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sample table on MSSQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  value FLOAT,
  formula NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('45.6452','/0.055');
```

now i want to select the table with the result of the 2 columns

```
select <computation> as Result from tbl
```

what is the correct query to generate the result that i want?

tried "Compute" and "Compute By" but it is not applicable

Note: I'm NOT allowed to change the schema of the table since all im doing is to generate a report with the result of the 2 columns indicated above

Comment: What is your expected O/P?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: what is "O/P"?

Comment: Do you want to apply the formula on the `value`? Like `45.6452 /0.055`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `CASE WHEN` clause, however the calculations should be known beforehand (and also should be supported in SQL server):

```
select case left(formula,1)
     when '/' then value / convert(float,stuff(formula,1,1,''))
     when '*' then value * convert(float,stuff(formula,1,1,''))
     when '+' then value + convert(float,stuff(formula,1,1,''))
     when '-' then value - convert(float,stuff(formula,1,1,''))
     when '%' then value % convert(float,stuff(formula,1,1,''))
   end as Result
from tbl
```

### [Sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53c2d/6)

Comment: @King King: I have an other answer with `substring` and `right`. Its working in `MS SQL Server`. But Its not working in `sqlfiddle`

Comment: @Ullas sounds strange, are you sure you select `SQL Server ...` (right at the top bar, beside `SQL Fiddle` logo)?

Comment: @KingKing: Sorry.. There it was `MySQL`. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this query

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(1000)
SET @query = ''
SELECT @query = @query + ' SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,value) + formula + ' as [RESULT]' FROM xtbl
EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: i like this solution, since any formula on my next column will compute by this solution, but it is not applicable also since this can't be used inside of a select query :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you concat (value, formula) and then execute as an SQL?

Example SQL Server:

```
 declare @left float = 45.6452;
 declare @right NVARCHAR(50) = '/0.055';
 declare @sql varchar(50) ;
 set @sql = 'select ' + cast(@left as varchar) + @right

 exec(@sql)
```

Result:

```
829.91272727
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the values together as characters and then executing the statement with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql= 'SELECT '+ CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(20)) + formula
           FROM tbl
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```